# Is this html invalid, span element effected by formatting

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This Html (that uses Bootstrap 4) works as I expected

```
 <h6>
        01 - 01 - Apache.wav <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Updated</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
            MusicBrainz
        </span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
            Discogs
        </span>
    </h6>
```

[image]
but if I remove pretty printing

```
<h6>01 - 01 - Apache.wav <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Updated</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">MusicBrainz</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Discogs</span></h6>
```

then it no puts padding between the badges.

[image: html]
Why is this, is it something to do with having text inside h6 and then a span, is my html incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an article explaining how the browser handles tabs and white spaces.
https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33

According to the article the tabs and new lines in your fist code snippet are converted to white spaces.

The author listed in points the mechanism followed by the browser (See point no 3).

Comment: Thanks that article explains it really well, (but it would be better if you posted more detail directly in your answer)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have removed the whitespace characters when merging everything into a single line:

```html
<h6>
    01 - 01 - Apache.wav <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Updated</span><!-- here is whitespace
    up to here --><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
        MusicBrainz
    </span><!-- more whitespace
spaces here --><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
        Discogs
    </span>
</h6>
```

became:

```html
<h6>01 - 01 - Apache.wav <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Updated</span><!-- no whitespace here --><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">MusicBrainz</span><!-- no whitespace here --><span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Discogs</span></h6>
```

Re-add the whitespace to achieve identical rendering:

```html
<h6>01 - 01 - Apache.wav <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Updated</span> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">MusicBrainz</span> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Discogs</span></h6>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but dont fully get it because only stripped newl lines not spaces, this doesnt seem the correct way to fix this, bit hacky. I assume from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/badge/ that badges shoud have some padding ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor Well, there are lots of spaces at the beginning of every line and you stripped those too

Comment: This has nothing to do with bootstrap or the _badge_ component, but is simply how browsers interpret HTML and whitespace nodes.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of you removed whitespace, so you need to add whitespace or you can add class mr-1(margin-right) to span

Answer (score 0):

Because of whitespace are removed, it needs to add whitespace or else you can add margin or padding to span tag.